# http post giving illegal state Exception

Tags: android, http-post, httpresponse

this is code which I use for HTTP post

```
public void postData() {

    //DineOutActivity doa = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("192.168.1.112/andro/index.php/androctrl/test/");

    try {

        //food item
     Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
     String fooditem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

     TextView mDateDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     String Date = mDateDisplay.toString();

     TextView mTimeDisplay  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
     String Time = mTimeDisplay.toString();



        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fooditem", "fooditem"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Date", "Date"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Time", "Time"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        Log.w("ADPORTAL", str);
        HttpStatus status;

        if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
        {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //result.setText("You are not registerd please register"
        }
        else
        {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}



    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
} 

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    // Read response until the end
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Return full string
    return total;
```

I use mTimeDisplay[Text View2] as the value from TimePicker Dialog.
And mDateDisplay [Texview4] as the value from DatePicker Dialog .

Following is my whole source code where I have used `postData()`

```
public class DineOutActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;
   /******************time picker**************/
        private TextView mTimeDisplay;
           private Button mPickTime;
           private int mHour;
           private int mMinute;
           private int mAmPm;

           static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID=1;

        static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /********************spinner***********/

        Spinner food = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> foodadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.item_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        foodadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        food.setAdapter(foodadapter);
        /**pick date*/

        mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
       /**pick time**/

        mPickTime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        // add a click listener to the button
        mPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                     public void onClick(View v) {

                           showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
                     }
              });

        // get the current time
        final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        mAmPm = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

        // display the current date
       upTimeDisplay();


/*****************************pick date***********************************/
        // add a click listener to the button
        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v1) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        // get the current date
        final Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int mDst = date.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
        int mAmPm = date.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);

        // display the current date (this method is below)
        updateDisplay();
    }

    // updates the date in the TextView




   private String upTimeDisplay()
   {
     //  mTimeDisplay.setText(new  
           //    StringBuilder().append(pad(mHour)).append(":").append(pad(mMinute)).append(pad(mAmPm)));
       mTimeDisplay.setText(new  
                  StringBuilder().append(mHour).append(":").append(mMinute));
       mTimeDisplay.setTextColor(R.color.green);
    return null;
   }
  /** private Object pad(int mMinute2) {

       if(mMinute2>=10)
              return String.valueOf(mMinute2);
       else
              return "0"+String.valueOf(mMinute2);
}**/

   private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mtimeSetListener=new  
           TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

mHour=hourOfDay;
mMinute=minute;
int ampm;

upTimeDisplay();
}
};


    private String updateDisplay() {
        mDateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                    .append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
        mDateDisplay.setTextColor(R.color.green);
                 //   .append(mHour).append("_")
                  //  .append(mMinute).append("_")));
        return null;
    }

    // the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                    mDay);

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,mtimeSetListener,mHour,mMinute,false);
        }
        return null;
    }







public  void imageclick(View view)
{ 
    postData();
    //Intent where = new Intent(this, WhereToeat.class);
    //startActivity(where);
}

/**************/

public void postData() {

    //DineOutActivity doa = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("192.168.1.112/andro/index.php/androctrl/test/");

    try {

        //food item
     Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
     String fooditem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

     TextView mDateDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     String Date = mDateDisplay.toString();

     TextView mTimeDisplay  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
     String Time = mTimeDisplay.toString();



        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fooditem", "fooditem"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Date", "Date"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Time", "Time"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        Log.w("ADPORTAL", str);
        HttpStatus status;

        if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
        {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //result.setText("You are not registerd please register"
        }
        else
        {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}



    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
} 

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    // Read response until the end
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Return full string
    return total;
}
```

I am having an `Exception` in `postData` Method 
in line

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

The exception of the logcat is :

```
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     ... 11 more
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:577)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:292)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at com.crews.dineout.DineOutActivity.postData(DineOutActivity.java:243)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at com.crews.dineout.DineOutActivity.imageclick(DineOutActivity.java:209)
05-04 11:53:00.096: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     ... 14 more
```

I am running from mobile and which has a wifi connection
And I have internet permision.

Comment: Please don't capitalize your title "HTTP POST GIVING ILLEGAL STATE EXCEPTION" Its unnecessary.

Comment: okay i will edit it and i am trying according to your answer

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your URI is invalid. - 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html

You are missing the scheme- http

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.112/andro/index.php/androctrl/test/")
```

Comment: I am checking with the server side, by that time is it any error /mapping in before adding name value pair

Comment: I tried  with what you have said  but the data is being inserted as "fooditem" , 0000-00-00 , 00:00

Comment: what i mean to say is i cannot get the exact data to inserted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444473/http-post-data-not-inserted-but-showing-successful-response   check this

Comment: OK, i am going to answer the new question. If the reply helped you with IllegalStateException, please consider marking it resolved for the benefit of all.